# Symfony framework best pratice

Tags: symfony

I'm currently developing in Symfony 3 and I'm wondering what's (if there is) the best practice in the following case :

Supposed I have clients and orders entity, each order being linked to one client.
If I want to calculate the sum of the orders by client, what's the best way ?

- a function in the client class that parse the client's orders to sum them and return the result
- a function in the order's repository taking a client as parameter and returning a scalar result (... SUM(order.value) WHERE order.client =: client) ...)
- a function in the repository that returns all the orders of a client and then summing the values in the controller

Thanks for the help and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of the popularity of the phrase, there is no such thing as an objective "best practice".  It's always subjective and always depends on your specific problem.  Which is why these sorts of questions tend to be frowned upon, down voted and closed.

- a function in the client class that parse the client's orders to sum them and return the result

From a domain driven design point of view, this would be ideal.  Business logic in your business entity.  The problem is how many orders do you think a client will accumulate because this approach requires loading in all the orders for a given client.  A few dozen orders?  Probably fine.  A few thousand orders?  Might start to slow things up.  Maybe you could start with this approach and then refactor as the system grows?

- a function in the order's repository taking a client as parameter and returning a scalar result (... SUM(order.value) WHERE order.client =: client) ...)

This seems like it would be very efficient.  On the other hand, it starts to leak some of the client functionality into to the order domain.  Might become hard to maintain if you end up with many of these special functions scattered about.  But if this is the only one then it's probably fine.

- a function in the repository that returns all the orders of a client and then summing the values in the controller

Grabbing all the orders has the same scaling problems as the you first solution.  Do you really need the complete order just to sum it?  What the heck does summing mean anyways?  Putting business functionality inside a controller is generally not a good thing.  What if you need to calculate the sum in some other place as well?  On the other, it is Symfony, and quite a few Symfony apps do have rather fat controllers with plenty of business logic and work just fine.  So this might be the best approach if it fits in with the rest of your application.

And while you did not mention it, creating a ClientOrder service is also a possibility.

But at the end of the day it is really your decision.  No magical best practices are going to help.  I'd suggest writing a few tests just to make possible refactoring easier and then pick an approach that meets your current needs and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following is just my opinion, because this is not mentioned in the official doctrine best practices.

> a function in the client class that parse the client's orders to sum them and return the result

This would result in loading all the related orders from the database unless you mark the collection as "extra lazy" ([Extra Lazy Associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html)). But in my opinion you should not do that, as long as you're not working with the whole collection anyways.

> a function in the order's repository taking a client as parameter and returning a scalar result (... SUM(order.value) WHERE order.client =: client) ...)

This should be the way to go. You put all the "heavy lifting" into the Repository class and your application does not need to know how the repository gets the order count. Additionally you don't clutter your entity class with additonal functionality (imo they should only contain the data and more specific requests should be handled by the repositories).

> a function in the repository that returns all the orders of a client and then summing the values in the controller

This would load all the entities similar to variant 1, so don't do that unless you want to work with all the entities anyway.